# use fasttext by windows and build the binary file

Tags: python, deep-learning, fasttext

I would be very thankful if I can have your help, I want to use fasttext by windows 10 (fastext work officially with mac and linux) which I have installed base on this hints

https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781789130997/1/ch01lvl1sec11/installing-fasttext

then I want to run this code in below (train prodigy sesne2vec)

I believe  I have fasttext properly in my computer

I have tried to run this

https://github.com/explosion/sense2vec/blob/master/scripts/04_fasttext_train_vectors.py

but I faced with this error

I  used this command

```
    !python 04_fasttext_train_vectors.py -c 10 "C:/Users/moha/Documents/Models/Debug/fasttext.dll" "   ../data/output02" "../data/output04"
```

```
   [i] Created temporary merged input file
   ..\data\output02\s2v_input.tmp
   [i] Training vectors
   C:/Users/moha/Documents/Models/Debug/fasttext.dll skipgram -thread 10 -input ..\data\output02       \s2v_input.tmp -output ..\data\output04\vectors_w2v_300dim -dim 300 -minn 0 -maxn 0 -minCount 10 -verbose 2
   [+] Deleted temporary input file
   ..\data\output02\s2v_input.tmp

   [x] Failed training vectors

   The system cannot execute the specified program.
```

as you see I used "fasttext.dll" as a binary file

I think the question is how can I Build fastText using command equivalent to" make"  in windows? for mac and Linux the instruction is so :

(

```
Building fastText using make (preferred)
wget https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/archive/v0.9.1.zip
unzip v0.9.1.zip
cd fastText-0.9.1
make
```

This will produce object files for all the classes as well as the main binary fasttext. If you do not plan on using the default system-wide compiler, update the two macros defined at the beginning of the Makefile (CC and INCLUDES).

Building fastText using cmake
For now this is not part of a release, so you will need to clone the master branch.

```
 git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git
cd fastText
mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..
 make && make install
```

)
which make a binary file that I can use it in the script, the question is can I build this file using windows?

Answer (score 1):

Update : 
I've downloaded fastext.exe from https://pypi.org/project/fasttext-win/#files
and I've completed the training process, here the screenshot

[fasttext.exe did the trick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/080Kg.png)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution!

Answer (score -1):

Different with me, I've try to train data using sense2vec script but I used bin-file from pre-trained vector that I've downloaded before:

```
d:/sense2vec/04_fasttext_train_vectors.py
ℹ Created temporary merged input file
D:\sense2vec\s2v_input.tmp
ℹ Training vectors
D:/fasttext/yahoo_answers.bin skipgram -thread 10 -input D:\sense2vec\s2v_input.tmp -output D:\sense2vec\vectors_w2v_300dim -dim 300 -minn 0 -maxn 0 -minCount 50 -verbose 2
✔ Deleted temporary input file
D:\sense2vec\s2v_input.tmp
✔ Successfully trained vectors
D:/sense2vec/
ℹ Creating vocabulary
D:/fasttext/yahoo_answers.bin dump D:\sense2vec\vectors_w2v_300dim.bin dict > D:\sense2vec\vocab.txt
✔ Successfully created vocabulary file
D:\sense2vec\vocab.txt
```

The result is vocab.txt with 0 kb file (empty)

Comment: at last I figure it out, how to make it works. I downloaded compiled fastetxt from https://github.com/xiamx/fastText/releases and instead of using fasttext.dll you can use fasttext.exe for the fasttext binary file